# Google Search Console Script - Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) Error

Tags: javascript, php, google-search-console

I'm getting the following CORB error when running my bookmarklet and targeting a php script to reaches out to search console and returns all quarty values for the URL the bookmarklet is run on.

Error:
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked a cross-origin response.
1 request
search-console-queries.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsomedomain.edu%2Fpayingforcollege%2Findex.php&callback=handleResponse

Bookmarklet Script:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar script %3D document.createElement('script')%3Bscript.src %3D 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.somedomain.edu%2F_resources%2Fphp%2Fabstraction_layers%2Fgoogle%2Fsearch-console-queries.php%3Furl%3D' %2B encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) %2B '%26callback%3DhandleResponse'%3Bdocument.body.appendChild(script)%3Bwindow.handleResponse %3D function(data) %7B console.log(data)%3B %7D%7D)()%3B
```

Search Console PHP Script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // Explicitly set the content type to JSON
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    // Send OK status for preflight, no further action needed
    http_response_code(200);
    exit;
}

$clientId = 'jkwekjwrjlwr-4u2928482498248.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$clientSecret = 'RANDO-M4298424-3813938938913';
$redirectUri = 'https://somedomain.edu/_resources/php/abstraction_layers/google/search-console-queries.php';

// Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoints
$authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';
$tokenUrl = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';

session_start();

function getAccessToken($clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUri, $code) {
    global $tokenUrl; // Access global variable within function
    $tokenData = [
        'code' => $code,
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    ];
    $opts = [
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'content' => http_build_query($tokenData)
        ]
    ];
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response = file_get_contents($tokenUrl, false, $context);
    return json_decode($response, true)['access_token'];
}

// OAuth flow
if (!isset($_GET['code']) && !isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $authParams = http_build_query([
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
        'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly',
        'access_type' => 'offline'
    ]);
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl . '?' . $authParams);
    exit;
}

if (isset($_GET['code']) && !isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = getAccessToken($clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUri, $_GET['code']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $accessToken = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    // Validate the URL parameter to prevent injection attacks
    $url = filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    if ($url === false) {
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'Invalid URL']);
        exit;
    }

    // Calculate dates
    $startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-30 days"));
    $endDate = date('Y-m-d'); // Today's date

    // Search Console API request
    $apiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/' . urlencode($url) . '/searchAnalytics/query';
    $requestBody = json_encode([
        'startDate' => $startDate,
        'endDate' => $endDate,
        'dimensions' => ['query'],
        'rowLimit' => 1000
    ]);

    $opts = [
        'http' => [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken\r\n" .
                    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
            'content' => $requestBody
        ]
    ];
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $response = file_get_contents($apiUrl, false, $context);

    // Output the response
    echo $response;
}
?>
```

I've tried adding CORS headers and applied some htaccess headers to the target domain.

Comment: `header('Location: ' . $authUrl . '?' . $authParams);` - that can't work in this context. The browser is expecting to get a resource back that can be interpreted as JavaScript, but you are sending it to Google's login page instead. You need to redirect the _frontend_ to that URL, not your JavaScript resource.